# Install kubernetes on ubuntu server 22.4 with virtualbox

Tags: kubernetes, ubuntu-22.04

I have installed virtualbox on my windows laptop. And then I have installed ubuntu server 22.4.

https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-kubernetes-on-ubuntu

I have followed that link mentioned above.

**here is my 10-kubeadm.conf file**

```
 # Note: This dropin only works with kubeadm and kubelet v1.11+
[Service]
Environment="KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS=--bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf"
Environment="KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS=--config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
Environment="KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--fail-swap-on=false"
# This is a file that "kubeadm init" and "kubeadm join" generates at runtime, populating the KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS variable dynamically
EnvironmentFile=-/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env
# This is a file that the user can use for overrides of the kubelet args as a last resort. Preferably, the user should use
# the .NodeRegistration.KubeletExtraArgs object in the configuration files instead. KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS should be sourced from this file.
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/kubelet
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet $KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS $KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS
```

when I run this command

```
sudo kubeadm init --control-plane-endpoint=master-node --upload-certs


W0122 12:30:59.668914   77279 version.go:104] could not fetch a Kubernetes version from the internet: unable to get URL "https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable-1.txt": Get "https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable-1.txt": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
W0122 12:30:59.668985   77279 version.go:105] falling back to the local client version: v1.28.2
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.28.2
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
error execution phase preflight: [preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
        [ERROR Port-10259]: Port 10259 is in use
        [ERROR Port-10257]: Port 10257 is in use
        [ERROR Port-10250]: Port 10250 is in use
[preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can make a check non-fatal with `--ignore-preflight-errors=...`
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
```

And when I try to kill all thes PID they just restart. I have already uninstall the ubuntu server and started from scratch. But still the same issue and I always stuck at the step 10

Comment: `netstat -tulpn | grep -E "10259|10257|10250"`

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to identify what's using those ports listed with this command:

```
sudo netstat -tunlp
```

Once you have that, you can see what application is conflicting with the KubeCTL instances.

Comment: Let's suppose that today I have created a cluster with 1 master and 2 worker nodes. Today It will work but when I try to access the cluster tomorrow it does not work. It still has the old ip address. 
Does someone know where we need to change the ip address?
Currently I have discovered that the ip address is in 
/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml
and
/etc/kubernetes/manifests/etcd.yaml

And changing the ip address, restarting container runtime, containerd and kubelet. The issue is still there